# On Services, Daos and in between - a beginner's dilemma

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, service, dao

I'm pretty new to layered architecture, + spring + hibernate
after reading some guides on how the class hierarchy is supposed to be -

i came up with this structure:

```
public interface GenericDAO {

   public <T> T getItemById(long id, Class<T> c);

   public <T> int save(T... objectsToSave);

   public <T> int saveOrUpdate(T... objectsToSave);

   public <T> int delete(T... objectsToDelete);
       .
       .
}
```

now all my other daos impls are using this generic dao as a private field in order to use its basic methods:
i.e:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDao {

      @Autowired
      private GenericDAO dao;

      @Override
      public int deleteUser(User u) {
        return dao.delete(u);

      }

      .
      .
      .
}
```

My services are like this :

```
 @Service
 public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

     @Autowired
     private UserDao userDao;


     @Transactional(readOnly = false)
     public int deleteUser(User u) {
         return userDao.deleteUser(u);
     }
         .
         .
         .
 }
```

I don't get why i need a UserDaoImpl , CarDaoImpl, XDaoImpl in my project? it seems really redundant since all the XDaoImpls looks the same:

```
 @Repository
 public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDao {

      @Autowired
      private GenericDAO dao;

      @Override
      public int deleteUser(User u) {
        return dao.delete(u);

      }

      .
      .
      .
}

@Repository
public class CarDAOImpl implements CarDao {

      @Autowired
      private GenericDAO dao;

      @Override
      public int deleteCar(Car c) {
        return dao.delete(c);

      }

      .
      .
      .
}

@Repository
public class XDAOImpl implements XDao {

      @Autowired
      private GenericDAO dao;

      @Override
      public int deleteX(X c) {
        return dao.delete(c);

      }

      .
      .
      .
}
```

I could just not create any XDaoImpl and just use the GenericDaoImpl instead and save alot of classes creation, no?

If ill need any complex actions like deleteUserCar(User u) i can just implement the logic in the service:

```
UserService {
          public void deleteUserCar(User u) {
             Car c = u.getCar();
             CarService cs.deleteCar(c);

          }  
}
```

Am i missing something?
can anyone please offer an example that using only GenericDaoImpl  instead of XDaoImpl will make me regret it?

thanks

Comment: why don't you declare your specific dao interfaces as sub interfaces of your generic interface and create a generic `BaseDaoImpl` with the proper implementation of the basic methods. like this: `public interface UserDao extends GenericDao<User> {` and `public class UserDAOImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<user> implements UserDao {`

Comment: From a pragmatic perspective (readability: getCar() vs get(), logging: XDaoImpl vs GenericDaoImpl in logs and stack traces), I would prefer the XDaoImpl approach over GenericDaoImpl. I'm happy with the trade-off here in having to write more boilerplate code in the dao layer.

Comment: Marco Forberg - i don't do the extend since it will be a pain to autowire the dao's (there will be too many nominees for the injection)

Comment: weird. we never had a problem wiring our dao ressources. do your service classes have use the classes or the interfaces?

Comment: Interfaces, if i have genericDaoImpl and UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl than when i autowire: @autowired  UserDao dao;   spring dont know if to attach the generic or the user impl

Comment: it might help to stop using the generic impl for anything else than as base class. ideally your service layer shouldn't know of the impls at all.

Answer (score 1):

- Your service will later on invoke businesslogic instead of just passing methods to the DAO. It may validate values (e.g. does it exist and is it supposed to be unique), run calculations (e.g. `int getStock() { return bought - sold; }` and so on.
- A generic DAO is great, though consider a `abstract class` instead of an `interface`. This way you don't need to create multiple `create()`s, just extend the abstract DAO (e.g. `CarDAO extends AbstractDAO<Car>`).
- Your extended DAO will pass the `class` it handles to the generic abstract DAO (as seen in previous example).
- Your extended DAO will later on implement extra methods that only apply on that particular object, e.g.: `List<Car> getCarsWithColor(Color color)`.
- Your Service -> DAO relationship is not always one-on-one. Consider these DAOs: `TruckDAO`, `CarDAO`, `VanDAO` with objects `Truck extends Vehicle`, `Car extends Vehicle`, `Van extends Vehicle`. Do you need three services, or will a `VehicleService` cover it (will you run logic for all `Vehicle`s perhaps)?
- Reconsider the use of interfaces, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90851/is-it-just-me-or-are-interfaces-overused) question applies to `C#` but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is: Just keep it simple! Please don't create too much abstraction that leads to too much complexity, remember that if you create create so much code that you don't need, that code you will be forced to mantain: tons of trash that you don't even know what was its purpose, tons of code that obscure the real objectives of your application.

So in this particular case I advice to :

1. Forget about creating DAO interfaces: They are intended to abstract the DAO implementations in order to switch 'easily' from databases (eg. MySQL to SQLServer) but think!: that is a really rare thing: it is more common to switch systems than to switch databases
2. Put that GenericDao in the trash (The world is not about CRUDs, go to your stakeholders and ask what they really need)
3. Use a simple DAO Layer and Service Layer, you  can implement that with Spring: I imagine
   that you can use a SimpleJDBCTemplate in DAO Layer and call that DAO methods in Service layer
4. Why use Spring after all? Have you asked yourself what's its purpose?, Currently I work with MyBatis in this way: I create Mappers (something analogous to DAOs) that are called by POJO services. Simple, useful and straightforward, no Spring, plain old Java, works like champ.